# Angular8 get image from url but using db

Tags: node.js, angular

Is there a way to write urls in html, but get the image from db instead of a folder?

my goal is :
HTML (img.path is some url)
`<img src={{img.path}}>`

ts (as example):

```
getImage(String : url) {
    getFileFromDb(url);
    return image;
}
```

I'm trying to make a angular project using lots of images. For front-end, I know there two ways to get a image, using html (login.html):

`<img src='assets/img/loginBanner.jpg'>`

or using db (loginBanner.ts):

```
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);      
reader.onload = () => {          
img.readerResult = reader.result;
img.blob = blob;
};
```

Unforturnatly, these two both have disadvantages

There's tons of images we'll use, it's not probable to put all of it in "assets/img" folder.
But if using db, we have to send all the images everytime, that seems like a waste on the boardband.

Comment: The front end can't directly go to the db (and shouldn't because performance matters) You need to build a backend to read the data from a db,  encode it and send to the front end.  That being said, I don't see how you would store images in a database efficiently. Ideally you need an actual file storage system like `S3`, `FireStore` etc. all of which have their own APIs to read/write.  A distributed FS will optimize reads fore more frequently accessed files

Comment: In addition, you should also consider lazy loading. If you have hundreds of images, no human being can look at all of them at once. You can gradually load more as they are processed (i.e. when going to the next page, or when scrolling to the bottom)

Comment: `But if using db, we have to send all the images everytime` --> this also makes no sense. You have to transfer to image data no matter how you are reading it. The images live on a remote server and not the client's personal devices. Even if they are  in the assets folder, they are still transmitted

Comment: I see, thank u very much for pointing my mistake, I'll try it asap.

As for "sending all images everytime", it's about the browser will save some static files for a while (sorry for not telling precisey). And this mechanism definately is a efficient way to make the website load faster.